# how to optimize firebase function's response speed

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I use firebase function base on nodejs 6 and firestore,my simple function like this is always slow.I also found when i use set/add firestore in function,it always slow maybe 5-10 second
this is index.js,app get response from this queryUserDoc api.

`

```
const accountModel = require('./account');
exports.queryUserDoc = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const uid = context.auth.token.uid;
    return accountModel.getUserDocByUid(uid)
        .then(doc => {
            return JSON.stringify(({'errCode': ERROR_SUCCESS, 'data': doc.data()}));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return JSON.stringify(({'errCode': err}));
        });
});
```

`
account.js is below:

```
function getUserDocByUid(uid) {
    return db.collection(DB_COLLECTION_USER).doc(uid).get();
}
```

when my app call this api,i found it so slowly.console is below
[image]

Comment: Also posted on https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/443

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What has worked for me and increased significantly the speed of firebase functions, was to update the location of my functions. I'm located in Europe so the default was initially set to `us-central1` . After updating to `europe-west1` speed went from ~5 seconds to ~600ms. It's relatively easy to change the region as described here  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations 
I've just followed their example and i was ready to go

Comment: I try it but not work,I use console to show timestamp,find the all time used in db.collection.doc().get, this line average use 2.5 seconds or more.

Comment: My location and VPN Settings were wrong just now, you are right,I change location from us to japan, the performance is 200ms, but I don't know why location cause firestore db query slow. At the beginning，my three vpn is in USA,korean and jp,my function is in us,there are all slow,but when i change server to jp,the db query is quick that i use which the three vpn,so I think the reason not the network,maybe the default server location us load is too high pressure

Comment: That's great! I'm glad that it has helped you