# Firebase / Cloud Function is very slow

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Cloud Function that does the following:

```
const firestore = require('firebase-admin')
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const regex = require('../../utils/regex')

exports = module.exports = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called while authenticated.')
  }

  if (!data['displayName']) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'An display name must be provided.')
  }

  if (!regex.noSpecialCharactersExceptSpace.test(data['displayName'])) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('input-validation-failed', 'Your display name cannot have special characters in it.')
  }

  return firestore.firestore().collection('profiles').doc(context.auth.uid)
    .update({
      displayName: data['displayName']
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.info('Successful public profile update user='+ context.auth.uid)
      return { text: 'Your profile has successfully been updated' };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error updating public profile user=' + context.auth.uid + ' error=' + error)
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'An error happened, our team will look into it.')
    })
})
```

From my front-end, when I call this function, it can take up to 20-30 seconds for it to complete and return a status code. This delay really disrupts the user experience.

What's the best way to improve the response time?

**Testing**

1. Direct calls to Firestore from the UI resolve incredibly quickly. Thus, it seems unlikely that the problem is DNS from our side.
2. Other API calls to Cloud Function from the UI, like "Invite a Friend", resolve quickly, and are not affected by this fault.
3. Calls to other Cloud Functions, which do not return a Promise, but do things like send emails with Postmark, are **not** affected by this fault and also resolve incredibly quickly. Thus, it seems that the problem isn't the location of the Firebase project (`us-central1`). Although changing the location hasn't been tested.
4. The fault only occurs on this one function. The one copied and pasted above.
5. The only difference between the affected function, and our other functions, is that the one with the fault returns a Promise for a Firestore operation.

Comment: Please edit the question to include how you are collecting your benchmarks.

Comment: We click on the button, and it takes 20-30 seconds to complete. That's our benchmark. Is there anything in our code that could indicate why it's taking that long?

Comment: There are many factors in there: 1) the time it takes for your client code to make the call, 2) the time it takes Cloud Functions to wake up and start work, 3) the time it takes to actually execute your code, most notably of which is 4) the updating of the document in Firestore. Did you already investigate how much time each step takes, and if one of them is the culprit?

Comment: Yes, that's a bit mysterious. What does the network panel say--is the bulk of the time shown as waiting for server response. I've heard of people complaining about start-up latency for cloud functions, but they're usually talking about 1-2 seconds when they wanted 100-200ms. Some people have reported good results from providing a service account to cut down on authentication time. But dozens of seconds sounds like it could be some kind of DNS problem etc. Anyway, is there some particular reason you're not doing this on the front-end?

Comment: See this answer to a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706030/4815718

Comment: Thank you everybody! I've edit the question to answer your questions :)